# btBvhTriangleMeshShape useQuantizedAabbCompression Crash

Tags: c++, bullet-physics, crash

I use btBvhTriangleMeshShape for static world collision. Generally this works fine, but recently I have encountered situations where the construction of btBvhTriangleMeshShape would crash.

In debug builds I get an assert from:

```
btQuantizedBvh::quantize(unsigned short *,class btVector3 const &,int)
btQuantizedBvh::mergeInternalNodeAabb(int,class btVector3 const &,class btVector3 const &)
btQuantizedBvh::buildTree(int,int)
btOptimizedBvh::build(class btStridingMeshInterface *,bool,class btVector3 const &,class btVector3 const &)
btBvhTriangleMeshShape::buildOptimizedBvh(void)
btBvhTriangleMeshShape::btBvhTriangleMeshShape(class btStridingMeshInterface *,bool,bool)
```

If I disable useQuantizedAabbCompression during construction the issue does not occur and all appears to work well.

Are there some requirements for the mesh geometry that I am missing?